# Error: SPU Swap Partition: Disk Temporary Work Space is full by query having row_number() over (partition by) clause : Netezza

Tags: netezza, row-number

Db used: Netezza

Below query throw error
as

**Error: SPU Swap Partition: Disk Temporary Work Space is full**

```
(SELECT A.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MDLX_CASE_NB ORDER BY PAID DESC) AS RNK_NEW
FROM ANLA1.FPA_RANK_OLD A)
DISTRIBUTE ON (CLAIM_NB);
```

From the plan file, I can see given table is having 1.7B records and I feel it is processing that much record in temp space due to which error is thrown.

If my understanding is correct then can we have any alternate of above query or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ideas:

1. the MDLX_CASE_NB has an uneven distribution. Test it by doing a ‘select MDLX_CASE_NB,count(*) numbof FROM ANLA1.FPA_RANK_OLD A group by 1 order by numbof Desc’. In that case please get back with the results, and we can discuss what to do
2. The columns behind A.* are very wide. In that case you can try to change the above query to use Rowid and the join it back:

`create temp table x as 
SELECT Rowid as row_id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MDLX_CASE_NB ORDER BY PAID DESC) AS RNK_NEW
FROM ANLA1.FPA_RANK_OLD A
DISTRIBUTE ON (random);
Select A.*, RNK_NEW 
From ANLA1.FPA_RANK_OLD A 
Join x 
On x.row_id=a.rowid;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lars. I will get back to you on 1st point.

Comment: Output for point 1
```
MDLX_CASE_NB | NUMBOF

--------------+-----------
           | 596440824
1515527110 | 780

1832658084 | 738

1416085893 | 682

1484982733 | 602

1610486571 | 542

1562371258 | 536

1626891487 | 534

1815410220 | 530

1445748330 | 522

1774537190 | 498

1626816007 | 496

1445801658 | 496

1473360433 | 490

1484978103 | 482

1473683091 | 478

1562306041 | 473

1327126871 | 472

1774188634 | 458

1445748390 | 448

1017582599 | 441

1272118783 | 434

```

Above output is not complete, rest are in next comment.

Comment: 1832437315 | 430
1300494571 | 426
1402021795 | 424
1107878118 | 424
1815192761 | 424
1416067136 | 422
1445958027 | 416
1301124372 | 416
1815703556 | 416
1358281094 | 414
1772946793 | 408
1780215165 | 404
1577610767 | 402
1773120299 | 402
1610517957 | 400
1445748342 | 396
1484930350 | 396
1445748354 | 392
1530105278 | 390
1092780699 | 387
1358748543 | 384
1167689422 | 384
1815654307 | 382
1358059857 | 380
1445748402 | 380
1773623053 | 378
1643162529 | 378
1258842226 | 377
1545138395 | 376
1780160689 | 374
1313000057 | 374
1344118303 | 374

Sorry for formatting.

Comment: Im not sure how to read this... are there 780 rows with the most frequent MDLX_CASE_NB =1515527110? In that case I guess it’s fairly evenly distributed...

Comment: More importantly: did you try the code for idea #2?

Comment: yeah... Thanks. 
Re-written Query worked fine without error.

Comment: Cool. I guess your record size is probably wide. How many columns? Any large strings or similar?